# BigQuery query failed with error: "Unexpected. Please try again."

Tags: google-bigquery

The following query is failing with the error message: "Unexpected.  Please try again."

```
SELECT sapId as SAP_ID, accessionId as ACCESSION_ID, diagnosticSetId as DIAGNOSTIC_SET_ID
, if( pimsSoftwareCode is null, 
    if((feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'Android')) OR (feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'iOS'))
        , 'MOBILE', 'ONLINE'
    )
,'PIMS') as MODE
, if(feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'iOS'),
    'iOS'
    ,if(feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'Android')
        , 'Android', null)) as MOBILE_OS
, date(usec_to_timestamp(createAuditDate)) as DATE
, time(usec_to_timestamp(createAuditDate)) as TIME
FROM [20141104Android_backup.EventLog]
where month(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(createAuditDate)) = 10
and year(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(createAuditDate)) = 2014
and xUserAgent != 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)'
and ( (feature = 'Result_View' and appUrl contains '/app/viewCumulative') or (feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'Android')) or (feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'iOS')) );
```

When I modify the following line:

```
if(feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'iOS'),
    'iOS'
    ,if(feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'Android')
        , 'Android', null))
```

to be:

```
if(feature = 'MOBILE_JOB' and action = 'VIEW_JOB' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'iOS'),
'iOS'
,if(feature = 'Result_View' and REGEXP_MATCH(xUserAgent, 'Android')
    , 'Android', null))
```

the query works just fine.  I can provide the failing job id if needed.  I'm at a total loss to understand why the first variant fails and the second works just fine.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: if it involves debugging, always include a job id please

Comment: Job ID: vetconnectplus-shared:job_S3jDs68IVHTk71aL6uJSH0q4lOI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal error for your job was `Field 'MOBILE_OS' is incompatible with the table schema: Type mismatch: actual 'TYPE_BOOL' vs. expected 'TYPE_STRING'`.  We should surface this error better instead of giving the "Unexpected.  Please try again." message.

I've seen this previously when using a literal null, since the query engine usually interprets it as type boolean.  Try using `STRING(null)` instead of `null` in your IF statement.